# Possibility of making diagonal elements of a square matrix 1,if matrix has only 0 or 1

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Let `M` be an n x n matrix with each entry equal to either 0 or 1. Let `m[i][j]`
denote the entry in row `i` and column `j`. A diagonal entry is one of the
form `m[i][i]` for some i. Swapping rows `i` and `j` of the matrix `M` denotes the following action:

we swap the values `m[i][k]` and `m[j][k]` for `k = 1, 2 ..... n`. Swapping two columns
is defined analogously We say that `M` is re arrangeable if it is possible to swap some of the pairs of rows and some of the pairs of columns (in any sequence) so that,
after all the swapping, all the diagonal entries of `M` are equal to 1.

(a) Give an example of a matrix `M` that is not re arrangeable, but for
which at least one entry in each row and each column is equal to !.

(b) Give a polynomial-time algorithm that determines whether a matrix
`M` with `0-1` entries is re-arrangeable.

I tried a lot but could not reach to any conclusion please suggest me algorithm for that.

Comment: With the right wording, this could be a pretty good post on math.stackexchange; the linear-algebra nerds over there could probably give a good theoretical background to it.

Comment: If I understood right, we are allowed to swap elements in a same column. So it is a matter of counting the number of 1s in each column. If n is odd every column must have at least two 1s except the center column. Center column can have one. If n is even, every column should have at least two 1s. Therefore algorithm is even linear. I might be missing something big.

Comment: If you interpret the matrix as a digraph adjacency matrix, then you can show this problem is equivalent to determining whether the graph can be decomposed into strongly connected components.  Hopefully that's enough of a hint.  Play around with the transformations themselves (and try to think of those as merely shifting row and column labels).  As for part (a), try the matrix `[0,1,1;1,0,0;1,0,0]` and interpret that as a graph.  Is there a directed cycle?  If the graph did have a directed cycle, can you arrange the matrix so that the diagonal elements were the edges of the cycle?

Comment: @Nirk I'm afraid I can't follow your hints - it looks like doing a topological sort to get an upper triangular matrix but that is not what is required here. A matrix consisting of a single diagonal of 1s does not correspond to a cycle but solves the problem. A matrix entirely 1s solves the problem and is a cycle. A matrix with top and left 1s is a cycle but does not solve the problem. An empty matrix is neither a cycle nor solves the problem so I think I have all four combinations.

Comment: @mcdowella by bubbling the last column up to the front, you have a cycle (if you interpret the first column of that matrix to be the same node as the first row).  So moving the column back to the end merely shifts the label for the first column to the end

Answer (score 0):

I think this post is on topic here because I think the answer is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. Consider the job of putting a 1 in column i, for each i. Each row could do some subset of those jobs. If you can find an assignment of rows such that there is a different row capable of putting a 1 in each column then you can make the matrix diagonal by rearranging the rows so that row i puts a 1 on column i.

Suppose that there is an assignment that solves the problem. Paint the cells that hold the 1s for the solution red. Notice that permuting rows leaves a single red cell in each row and in each column. Similarly permuting columns leaves a single red cell in each row and each column. Therefore no matter how much you permute rows and columns I can restore the diagonal by permuting rows. Therefore if there is any solution which places 1s on all the diagonals, no matter how much you try to disguise it by permuting both rows and columns I can restore a diagonal by permuting only rows. Therefore the assignment algorithm fails to solve this problem exactly when there is no solution, for example if the only 1s are in the top row and the leftmost column.